# Python argparse: optional two values argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

**Hello**:
I being trying to setup an argument, that when included in the command line will consume exactly two arguments, and when not presented will default to a list of two values. So far I have not found a way to do this. The following is my code:

```
_version="1.0.0"
_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Statmon: expandable 
server metrics retriever', usage="""
statmon.py [-a COUNT SECS] [-c CONFIG] [-o [FILE]] MODULE [PARAM ...]
statmon.py -? [-c CONFIG] MODULE
statmon.py -v""")
_parser.add_argument('-?', '--show', dest='show', default=False, action='store_true',
                     help='Request to show the metrics return by a statistics module.')
_parser.add_argument('-a', '--avg', dest='avg_ms', default=[1, 0], action='store', type=int, nargs='*',
                     help='Asks to display the average of COUNT samples within SECS time. Default one sample.')
_parser.add_argument('-c', '--conf', dest='config', default="/etc/statmon.conf", action='store', type=str,
                     nargs='+', help='Define the configuration file. Default is /etc/statmon.conf.')
_parser.add_argument('-o', '--outfile', dest='outfile', default=None, const=None, action='store', type=str,
                     nargs='?', help='Define the out file to write the stats. If not provided will biuld it.')
_parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', dest='ver', default=False, action='store_true',
                     help='Shows version of the command.')
_parser.add_argument('module', default=[], action='store', type=str, nargs='*',
                     help="The module that we should pull the metrics from and its parameters.")
_args = _parser.parse_args()
if _args.ver:
    print("{0}: {1}".format(_parser.description, _version))
    exit(0)
```

My issue is with option '-a'. I want it if provided to get the next two elements from the command line and lear the remaining for the other options. Right now I get no error. But, if I include it it will consume more than two elements of the command line. See the following examples:

```
$ python statmon.py cpu
Option -a: [1, 0]
{"USER": 0.0, "NICE": 0.0, "SYS": 0.0, "IDLE": 0.0}
```

Now providing the option:

```
$ python statmon.py -a 10 10 cpu
usage:
statmon.py [-a COUNT SECS] [-c CONFIG] [-o [FILE]] MODULE [PARAM ...]
statmon.py -? [-c CONFIG] MODULE
statmon.py -v
statmon.py: error: argument -a/--avg: invalid int value: 'cpu'
```

My question is how do I instruct argparse that I have an optional argument that consumes two and only two elements of the command line? I need the default value of [1, 0] to be populated. If this is not possible I'll have to define two arguments "-C" and "-S", which I would like to avoid. I would also like to avoid defining a new argument "-m" to define the module. I would prefer for it to be a parameter of the command line other than an option.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Does `nargs=2` instead of star work?  `argparse` parses by position, not value.  So when you have a '*' positional following a variable nargs optional, the first one is greedy, taking all it can.  After all a star positional is just as happy with `[]` as `['a']`.

Comment: Does `module` have to be '*'?  If it isn't optional, leave the default required.  Or '+' if you want to provide more than one.  Then the parser will reserve the last string for this Action.  `argparse` does allow for required optionals and optional positionals, but -- it's simpler for and your users, if you don't mix the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `nargs='*'` then the following:

```
python statmon.py -a 10 10 cpu
```

will be interpreted as passing 3 arguments to `avg_ms`: [10, 10, 'cpu'] but because `cpu` is not a valid integer, `argparse` won't allow it, and that's the reason you are seeing this error:

```
error: argument -a/--avg: invalid int value: 'cpu'
```

What you want is:

```
python a.py -a 3 4 -- cpu
```

In which case `cpu` is assigned to `module` instead of `avg_ms`.

But as mentioned by @hpaulj, it should be enough to use `nargs=2`, and then this would work:

```
python a.py -a 3 4 cpu
```

Comment: Thank you @MondKin and hpaulj
I was stuck trying to define nargs='2', but I was getting an error. I have changed to nargs=2, and now I have an optional argument that consumes exactly 2 elements. So the solution was to do nargs=2. And not nargs='*' or nargs='2'. It works now. Also the option to have '-- cpu' as I had it defined also works. But I switch to nargs=2, this way it works as I was expecting it. Thank all.

Comment: Someone asked on the argparse bug/issues that it accepted `nargs='2'` as well as `nargs=2`.  https://bugs.python.org/issue32474 (closed)